# Rails jquery datepicker date pre-loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm using jquery datepciker in a Rails app.
I would like to have the date already filled in when the form page loads.  So, that the user can leave the date as-is or change it.

I was hoping the datepicker options would let me do that.

I tried this:

```
    $("#comment_status_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    setDate: Date.now
});
```

But, the date field was empty.

Do I have to do some ruby code in the model or controller?
Does datepicker have an option to do this?

Thanks!!

I figured out a way:

```
<%= f.input :status_date, :as => :string, :label => 'Date', :class => 'calendar hasDatepicker', :input_html => { :value => Date.today.to_s } %>
```

Comment: Try `Date.today` , `now` is for `Time.now` .

Comment: Thanks - Date.today worked.  But, I put it into the form instead of using datepicker option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way:

```
<%= f.input :status_date, :as => :string, :label => 'Date', :class => 'calendar hasDatepicker', :input_html => { :value => Date.today.to_s } %>
```